# How to print Brilliant problems of the week?

Tags: brilliant

I enjoy Brilliant's [Problems of the Week](https://brilliant.org/community/home/). Is there any way I can view all 15 on one page so that I can print them? I'd like to share them with friends.

Comment: I was able to do it by editing the CSS classes, but that’s a hack.